# É possível enviar dados no corpo e na url usando o método PUT e libcurl?

Tags: c++, http, libcurl

Estou tentando enviar os dados tanto na URL quanto no corpo usando o PUT a ideia era fazer com que ele funcionasse exatamente como o método POST, porém sendo o método PUT.

Isso porque vejo muitas requisições onde a url seria por exemplo /book/ e no corpo teria um JSON (com os dados usados para atualizar o elemento daquele id).

Estou tentando fazer isso usando a libcurl em C++, porém apesar do **REQUEST_METHOD** vir **PUT** eu não recebo os dados. A implementação do POST, GET e DELETE enviam os dados. Estou tendo problemas exclusivamente com o PUT a principio.

// Código em C++

```
I9CorpResponse * I9CorpRequest::request(int method, const char *url, const char *body, I9CorpRequestOptions * options) {
    I9CorpResponse * response = nullptr;
    long statusCode;
    CURLcode res;
    CURL *curl;
    char mBufferHeader[I9CORP_BUFFER_MESSAGE];
    char mTmp[I9CORP_BUFFER_MESSAGE];
    std::map<std::string, char *> mHeaders;
    struct curl_slist *chunk = nullptr;
    char *mBufferParam = nullptr;

    std::string content;

    curl = curl_easy_init();
    if (curl == NULL) {
        return nullptr;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, url);
    /* example.com is redirected, so we tell libcurl to follow redirection */
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1L);

    if (options != nullptr) {
        std::map<std::string, char *>::iterator it;
        mHeaders = options->getHeaders();
        it = mHeaders.begin();
        for (it = mHeaders.begin(); it != mHeaders.end(); ++it) {
            snprintf(mBufferHeader, I9CORP_BUFFER_MESSAGE, "%s: %s\0"
                    , it->first.c_str()
                    , it->second);
            chunk = curl_slist_append(chunk, mBufferHeader);
        }
        if (chunk != nullptr) {
            res = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, chunk);
        }
        if (body == nullptr) {
            mBufferParam = options->createQueryParams();
        }
    }

    switch (method) {
        case METHOD_GET:
            snprintf(mTmp, I9CORP_BUFFER_MESSAGE, "%s?%s\0", url, mBufferParam);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, mTmp);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1L);
            break;
        case METHOD_POST:
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1L);
            if (body != nullptr) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body);
            } else if (mBufferParam != nullptr) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, mBufferParam);
            }
            break;
        case METHOD_PUT:            
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
            if (body != nullptr) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, body);
            } else if (mBufferParam != nullptr) {
                curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, mBufferParam);
            }
            break;
        case METHOD_DELETE:
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "DELETE");
            snprintf(mTmp, I9CORP_BUFFER_MESSAGE, "%s?%s\0", url, mBufferParam);
            curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, mTmp);
            break;
    }

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, I9CorpRequest::callbackDataWrite);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, &content);

    /* Perform the request, res will get the return code */
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
    if (mBufferParam != nullptr) {
        free(mBufferParam);
    }

    /* Check for errors */
    if (res == CURLE_HTTP_RETURNED_ERROR) {
        response = new I9CorpResponse();
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &statusCode);
        response->setStatusCode(statusCode);
    } else if (res != CURLE_OK) {
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
                curl_easy_strerror(res));
    } else {
        response = new I9CorpResponse();
        curl_easy_getinfo(curl, CURLINFO_RESPONSE_CODE, &statusCode);
        response->setStatusCode(statusCode);
        response->setContent(content.c_str());
    }

    /* free the custom headers */
    if (chunk != nullptr) {
        curl_slist_free_all(chunk);
    }

    /* always cleanup */
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
    return response;
}
```

Nos exemplos que estou fazendo o body é nullptr e o mBufferParam tem conteúdo

> "lastname=Brito&name=Sileno&username=test"

Para testar eu escrevi o seguinte código em PHP, mas não consigo ler os valores, pois não chegam no php.

```
<?php

var_export(
    array(
        'server'=> $_SERVER,
        'get'=> $_GET,
        'post'=> $_POST,
        'request'=> $_REQUEST
    )

);
```

Answer (score 0):

Vou colocar como uma resposta porque a área de comentários é limitada.

Em primeiro lugar, teste antes com o curl em linha de comando.
Se funcionar na linha de comando então vai funcionar com a lib.

Em segundo, se você está querendo mandar forms via PUT em vez de POST, não sei se vai funcionar, acho que só o pessoal de web poderia dizer dizer alguma coisa, meu palpite é que vai dar problemas.

Em terceiro lugar, é possível subir dados via PUT, já fiz isso.
Mas a maneira de especificar o método que usei foi diferente, não foi CUSTOMREQUEST. Segue abaixo:

```
// avisa ao curl que vai ser feito um upload (vai ser usado o metodo PUT)

static int setupUploadMethod(CURL* curl)
{
   if (CURLcode cc = curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, 1))
   {
      int err = int(cc);
      log("...", err);
      return err;
   }

   return OK;
}
```